# Coordinate system of Unity's bizarre impulse property? Get forces in world space?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physx

OK this is officially the most difficult Unity3D question on the site:

---

If you have two objects in Unity, perhaps drag A around with your finger, when you collide with B,

these days Unity sensibly gives you the forces PhysX has decided to apply to that item in the collision. Just use `OnCollisionStay`...

```
Rigidbody rb;
void OnCollisionStay(Collision col)
  {
  if (rb.isKinematic) return;

  if ( col.impulse.x != 0f || col.impulse.y != 0f )
    Debug.Log(gameObject.name +" bashed, PhysX doing this .. "
      + col.impulse.x.ToString("f4") +" "
      + col.impulse.y.ToString("f4") +" "
      + col.impulse.z.ToString("f4")    );
  }
```

Looking at the doco http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision.html

the worthwhile one is `.impulse`

> impulse   The total impulse applied to this contact pair to resolve the collision.

Great. But. Unfortunately it is utterly mysterious **what coordinate system the impulse is being given in**.

Try it and see. It's nuts. Is it relative to the direction between the two colliding objects (i.e. between `transform` and `col.transform`) or is it in some local space (which?) Is it perhaps relative to `.relativeVelocity` vector?

What the hell is it?  It is stoopid.  Try and see.

I want the force applied simply *in world space* for goodness sake.

The **documentation has no info** and nobody is discussing it.

Comment: Give it time. It's only been an hour.. :)

Comment: I'd say it's likely to be in world space, and determined by a normal (either to a surface or edge) of one of the colliding elements. But I'd have to verify that.